# Bootstrap float utility

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The question is how to use [bootstrap float utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/)

Example:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="float-right">First</div>
  <div class="float-left">Second</div>
</div>
```

As you can see float does not work because row has

[image]

Bootstrap use flex strategy and it`s expected that float does not work, so why it`s added to BS4?

Comment: Why are you using 4.1.3 (when stable is 4.5) and reading the documentation for 5.0?

Comment: As the [documentation states](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/)... "Rows are wrappers for columns" Floats would be used outside the context of the flexbox grid, for example inside the content of a column

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap documentation says:

> Please be aware float utilities have no effect on flex items.

So don't use them on flex items. Use them on other things.

Floats aren't designed for laying things into columns. They are designed to let text wrap around other elements.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/75/75" class="float-left">
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Key here: `Floats aren't designed for laying things into columns. They are designed to let text wrap around other elements.` +1